# VB.net DataBinder

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with DataBinder in vb.net

```
<ItemTemplate><%#IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NMKAR") > 1, "Yes", "No")%></ItemTemplate>
```

I want to select, if NMKAR have more than one same value will return "Yes"

ex :

> ### NMKAR
>
> ONE
>
> ONE
>
> TWO

so the result will be

> ONE   |  YES
>
> TWO   |  NO

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your problem correctly so I am going to go with the assumption that you want to see the COUNT value of NMKAR. If this is the case, remember that bound repeating controls will display the number of rows available in your result set.

You would need to update your method of getting the data. So if you are using T-SQL you should update your select to get the distinct values of NMKAR and the amount of times it appears in the result set:

```
SELECT NMKAR, COUNT(NMKAR) AS NMKAR_COUNT FROM [TableName] GROUP BY NMKAR
```

If you are using a collection, iterate through the collection grabbing the first unique instance of each value and accumulate a total count for each value.

I would also suggest casting the bound object to the correct numeric type when evaluating a condition so that the type is not "guessed".

```
<%#IIf(CInt(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NMKAR")) > 1, "Yes", "No").ToString()%>
```